# Check Context Data Of Views - Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-urls

I am new to Django lets say I have modal like `college` and `department` like follow

```
class College(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField()
      is_active = models.BooleanField()

class Department(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField()
      college = models.ForeignKeyField()
```

Now I have views such as `DepartmentListView`, `DepartmentCreateView`, `DepartmentUpdateView` to list,create,update department. I want check is_active(True) of `college` before adding, list, update department. currently i am using `get_context_data` like follow

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(DepartmentListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    try:
        college_id = self.kwargs.get('position_id')
        context['college'] = College.objects.get(pk=college_id, is_active = True)
    except College.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404
    return context
```

but I am repeating the same block of code, again and again, I want to check `is_active` of college on all views in department app.how can I achieve this without repeating.

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a Class Method in College Model and use it in all Views?

This is my example code.

```
class College(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField()
      is_active = models.BooleanField()

      def get_is_active(self):
          return self.is_active
```

Define the method like above, and use like below in all view.

```
College.objects.get(id=college_id).get_is_active()
```

Comment: `get_is_active ` returns `True` or `False`. Which is exactly the same as what `is_active` gives you. How does that help?

Answer (score 0):

Use the shortcut [get_object_or_404](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404) Like this:

```
my_object = get_object_or_404(MyModel, pk=1)
```

Or in your specific case:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(DepartmentListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    college_id = self.kwargs.get('position_id')
    context['college'] = get_object_or_404(College, pk=college_id, is_active=True)
    return context
```

### Alternative

You can also define a [manger](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/managers/) for your College model:

```
class CollegeManager(models.Manager):
    def active(self):
        return super(CollegeManager, self).get_queryset().filter(is_active=True)


class College(URLMixin, BaseModel):
    objects = CollegeManager()
```

In your view you now can do:

```
get_object_or_404(College.objects.active(), pk=college_id)
```

Note that `.active()` can also return all active College objects useful for listings.

Your code duplication can be reduced even more. Create a manager method `get_active`:

```
def get_active(self, pk):
    return get_object_or_404(
        super(CollegeManager, self).get_queryset().filter(is_active=True),
        pk=pk
    )
```

In the view:

```
College.objects.get_active(college_id)
```

I never tried this last `get_active` example, ymmv.

Comment: Great, But I would like to know is it possible use `get_object_or_404` common to all views in `applicant` app, like URL starts with `college/{college_id}/departments/`

Comment: Ehm, yes, read the docs ;). get_object_or_404 is a Django builtin shortcut and available if you import it. Also your model manager is bound to your model. If you import your College model, the Collage.objects.custum_method() will be available as well.